# Can an application forward iPhone notifications to a web server?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, raspberry-pi

I would like to connect it to a raspberry pi that will react via it's gpio ports everytime the iPhone receives a notification.

Is it possible to create an application that can forward all notifications arriving to an iPhone to a webserver in order to process that 'notification' data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Looking at this, it seems like you'd have to get the `notification`n from the provider, since the `APNs` is a fairly closed system.

Comment: Cheers

And what if the notifications only came from sites you had to sign into from the app? e.g. log into Facebook via the app, then be able to pass on only notifications targeted for Facebook?